# How to use a String with Date to create a new File in Java

Tags: java, file

Why am I able to create a directory like this:
`new File("./HISTORY/www").mkdirs();`
But if I try to use a String, then nothing happens:

```
    String path = "./HISTORY/" + history_folder_name;
        new File(path).mkdirs();
```

This does not create the directory like the other one does. Why?
EDIT: this is how I am creating the folder name:

```
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
         Date now = new Date();
         String strDate = sdf.format(now);
         history_folder_name = "folderName";
```

It works fine if i take out the `HH:mm:ss:SSS` but I need them. What solution is there?

Comment: You may have some [Reserved characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Reserved_characters_and_words) in your folder name

Comment: I think you're right, ibut how can I get the date without these symbols so I can use it in the file name?

Comment: You need to change the date format. Perhaps somethis like this would help `yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSS` ?

Comment: Use other delimitors, with the `replace(":", ".")` method of String

Comment: Good opportunity to switch to `java.nio` and `java.time`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSS");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
     Date now = new Date();
     String strDate = sdf.format(now).replace(":", ".").replace("-", "_");
```